# Reversed array not saving in NodeJS Mongoose MongoDB

Tags: mongoose

I'm using NodeJS and Mongoose to store data to a MongoDB database.  It is mostly working fine, as I'd expect.

I have an array, as part of a Schema, saved to a database document in Mongoose.  It looks like this, in the Schema:

```
var GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    PlayerOrder: [Number],
    ...
}
```

When I call a `findOne(...)` to get this document from the DB, it works as expected, and I get a result, let's say `... [1,2,3,4] ...`.

Then, within the callback that's fired on successful `findOne(...)` execution, I modify some values, including PlayerOrder itself and other values.  I verify before saving to the DB, via console, that the changes were made to the local GameModel object.  **One of these changes is to reverse the PlayerOrder array using `game.PlayerOrder.reverse();'.**  Then I use the GameModel.save(...) function.

Here are some snippets of the code:

```
if (game.Turn >= game.PlayerCount) {
    console.log('Commuting to Phase 3.');
    game.Phase = 3;
    game.Turn = 0;
    // in phase 3, the player order is reversed; do that here
    console.log('player order before reverse: ' + game.PlayerOrder);
    game.PlayerOrder.reverse();
    // NOTE: this verifies that the array is correctly reversed in the model
    console.log('player order after reverse: ' + game.PlayerOrder);
}

game.save( function (err, game) {
    if (err) console.error(err);

    console.log('+ + + Execution successful; DB updated.');
});
```

Then, when I pull the same document from the DB again, all the changes I made are there.  In other words, after pulling the document I can see that all the changes I made to the document elements, such as player cash, game board state, etc, were all correctly made, and saved in the `save(...)` function.  EXCEPT for the reversed array, which never gets modified for some reason.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Mongoose can't track the changes made in the array when you used `reverse()`.

In order to notify the changes, use `markModified()`, like this:

```
if (game.Turn >= game.PlayerCount) {
    console.log('Commuting to Phase 3.');
    game.Phase = 3;
    game.Turn = 0;
    // in phase 3, the player order is reversed; do that here
    console.log('player order before reverse: ' + game.PlayerOrder);
    game.PlayerOrder.reverse();
    game.markModified('PlayerOrder'); // <== this line notifies Mongoose of the change

    // NOTE: this verifies that the array is correctly reversed in the model
    console.log('player order after reverse: ' + game.PlayerOrder);
}
```

More info on this, [Mongoose FAQ](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html) has some answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that works perfectly.  In the linked FAQ they suggest using Mongoose's `array.set(...)` method as well, but somehow I'm getting away with it without using that.  Just using `markModified(...)` is working for me.

Comment: Yes, the `set()` function is only for setting a single position in the array. Since you are reversing the entire array, it is not needed.